# function doesnt wait for response to be assigned before assigning the correct value

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have an xhr function on an ext js.file that sends values to a rest service and expects a response back. 
I call this function on an on click event btn. the first time it responds "undefined" and then when i fire the button again it responds with the correct value. im almost sure that my response is not instant but why cant the function wait until it has the value then asssign it to my return value before instead of sending me undefined.

```
var b;

function Transport(parameters, Page) {

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("POST", "http://***.***.***.***/" + Page, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state   changes.
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

            b = http.response;
        }
    }
    http.send(parameters);
    return b;
}
```

the  call of the function on the page

```
var transaction = Transport(parameters,"/mypage.php");
alert(transaction);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to use httprequest in Asynchronous mode. where http.send() returns immediately. you can try your code with Asynch to False.

```
var b;
function Transport(parameters,Page) { 
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
 http.open("POST", "http://***.***.***.***/"+Page, false);

  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
  http.send(parameters);
  b=http.response;
  return b;
 }
```

please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You are making an *asynchronous* request but trying to handle the result *synchronously*. Instead, use a callback.

```
function transport(parameters, Page, callback) { // not a constructor, cammel case
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "http://***.***.***.***/" + Page);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // don't set content-length, you'll get a warning

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        callback(this.response, this);
    });
    xhr.send(parameters);
    return xhr;
}
```

Then

```
transport(
    parameters,
    "/mypage.php",
    function (response) {alert(response);}
);
```

---

In ES6 we could write this as a [**Promise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
/**
 * Fetches a resource using XMLHttpRequest and a Promise
 * @param {String} url - The URL of the resource to get
 * @param {String|FormData|Blob|File} [postData] - Any data to POST
 * @param {String} [responseType] - The type of response to expect (defaults to document)
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function fetch(url, postData, responseType) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.responseType = responseType || 'document';
        x.addEventListener('load', e => res(x.response, x));
        x.addEventListener('error', e => {
            console.warn('XHR Error', url, e);
            rej(x.response, x);
        });
        if (!postData) {
            x.open('GET', url);
            x.send();
        } else {
            x.open('POST', url);
            if ('string' === typeof postData)
                x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            x.send(postData);
        }
    });
}
```

Then

```
fetch(Page, parameters, 'text').then(alert);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call Transport() to send the request, `b` already exists and has the value `undefined`.  The call is asynchronous and so returns immediately without waiting for the request to complete.  The request is still being processed in the background and has completed by the time you hit the button the second time.  When it completes it sets b, which is returned by the 2nd call.

The behavior would be more like what you're expecting if you changed your code to something like this:

```
function doSomethingWithMyData(data) {
    ...
}

function Transport(parameters, page) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("POST", "http://***.***.***.***/" + page, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state   changes.
        function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                doSomethingWithMyData(http.reponse);
            }
        }
    }
    http.send(parameters);
}
```

...

```
var transaction = Transport(parameters,"/mypage.php");
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt really solve my problem because there is an instance where i need to manipulate the data that is returned back not just display it as an alert. I would like to keep my function seperate to the rest of the function that manipulates the data.

Comment: @Alfred Alfizo Mosima All your example does is put the data in an alert.  I'll add more so you can see how to change it